# In KiCad (new user) I can no longer create a netlist file. It aborts with an error loading board file: Unknown token "export"

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, eda

My “Multi-Edit” notes on the first line "export:" See text immediately below:

```
(export (version D)
  (design
    (source C:\Users\vstamps\OneDrive\Documents\MyTutorial1.kicad\MyTutorial1.kicad.sch)
    (date "11/19/2021 7:51:24 PM")
    (tool "Eeschema (5.1.10)-1")
    (sheet (number 1) (name /) (tstamps /)
      (title_block
        (title "Control miniHFPA")
        (company "HF Projects")
        (rev 0)
        (date 9/7/2021)
        (source MyTutorial1.kicad.sch)
        (comment (number 1) (value ""))
        (comment (number 2) (value ""))
        (comment (number 3) (value ""))
        (comment (number 4) (value "")))))
```

When I first started working with my  first artwork, it worked for awhile and then broke. I am a novice KiCad user, but plenty of experienced with old ORCAD.

Comment: to me, the obvious thing to try, is to import the file instead of loading it